# Amazon S3 Access Denied - Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

i need set my images on aws, i already configure my bucket as public, but i just got "AccessDenied"

```
public boolean saveImage(String nome, String base64){
        try {
            byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64.split(",")[1]);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String fileName = nome+".png";
            BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(acessKey, secretKey);
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), new ObjectMetadata());
            AmazonS3 s3Client =
                    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("sa-east-1")
                            .withCredentials(new
                                    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                            .build();
            s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

my bucket its 100% public

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: ""; S3 Extended Request ID: ""; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to lack of permission to perform actions on s3 in your IAM user policy.Make sure the IAM user credentials you are using should have enough privileges to perform the desired action. Also, you can refer to this article by AWS for reasons and solution for 403 error in S3 - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/